# My app's minSdkVersion is 14 and targetSdkVersion is 21 but Google Play judge it just support Android 4.0~4.4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, version, android-5.0-lollipop

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.drakeet.seashell"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 80
    versionName "2.2"
}
```

Above code is in my gradle.build, and my app run perfectly in Android Lollipop (5.0), so I am puzzled that why Play judge and limit it just support Android 4.0~4.4, why not 5.0+?
Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have fix it.
just add:

```
maxSdkVersion 21
```

in the gradle.build nearby minSdkVersion.

Comment: Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible
Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: You should never use maxSdkVersion as mentioned in above comments.